# I am Trying to scrape overall product details like brand, ingredient and flavour

Tags: html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

Can anyone pls help me to scrape Flavour and brand details as key value pair using beautifulsoup. I am new in this:

Desired output would be

Flavour - Green Apple

Brand - Carabau

the html looks like this:
Html Code -

```
<tr class="a-spacing-small">
<td class="a-span3">
    <span class="a-size-base a-text-bold">Flavour</span>
</td>

<td class="a-span9">
    <span class="a-size-base">Green Apple</span>
</td>
```

```
<tr class="a-spacing-small">
<td class="a-span3">
    <span class="a-size-base a-text-bold">Brand</span>
</td>

<td class="a-span9">
    <span class="a-size-base">Carabau</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have take data as `html` and you can use `find` method on respective tag to get exact data also you can use `find_next()` alternatively

```
html="""<tr class="a-spacing-small">
<td class="a-span3">
    <span class="a-size-base a-text-bold">Flavour</span>
</td>

<td class="a-span9">
    <span class="a-size-base">Green Apple</span>
</td>
</tr>"""
```

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
dict={}
data=soup.find("td",class_="a-span3").find_next().text

data1=soup.find("td",class_="a-span9").find("span",class_="a-size-base").text
print(data+" - "+data1)
dict[data]=data1
```

Output:

```
Flavour - Green Apple
```

Comment: Thanks Bhavya, this worked. But if we have similar td tags for flavours and brand, how do we get all the details

Comment: If you want to find all tags use `find_all` method

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

**Select the `<tr>` and use `.stripped_strings` to get a list of strings inside `<tr>`.**

*Note: If you have multiple `<tr>` then use `.find_all()` to select each of it and do the same.*

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """
<tr class="a-spacing-small">
<td class="a-span3">
    <span class="a-size-base a-text-bold">Flavour</span>
</td>
<td class="a-span9">
    <span class="a-size-base">Green Apple</span>
</td>
</tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
tr = soup.find('tr')
print(list(tr.stripped_strings))
```

```
['Flavour', 'Green Apple']
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no need in `.stripped_strings` as mentioned by [Ram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70004018/15164646) since you can directly call a specific `CSS` selector which will be safer since it will grab data from specific elements, not from something else, and this doesn't create a dictionary key-value pair as you wanted.

You're looking for this:

```py
# ...

data = []

for result in soup.select('tr'):
    # CSS selector for flavour detail
    flavor_name = result.select_one('.a-span9 .a-size-base').text
    
    # appends to list() as a dict() -> key-value pair
    data.append({
        "flavour": flavor_name
    })

print(data)

# # [{'flavour': 'Green Apple'}]
```

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/I-am-Trying-to-scrape-overall-product-details#main.py) (*will return key-value pair*):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<tr class="a-spacing-small">
<td class="a-span3">
    <span class="a-size-base a-text-bold">Flavour</span>
</td>

<td class="a-span9">
    <span class="a-size-base">Green Apple</span>
</td>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# temp list()
data = []

for result in soup.select('tr'):
    # flavor = soup.select_one('.a-text-bold').text  # returns just Flavour word
    flavor_name = result.select_one('.a-span9 .a-size-base').text
    
    data.append({
        "flavour": flavor_name
    })

print(data)

# [{'flavour': 'Green Apple'}]
```

Access created data:

```py
for flavour in data:
    print(flavour["flavour"])

# Green Apple
```